# Malformed field path "" (InvalidArgumentException)

Tags: php, behat, automated-tests, mink, goutte

I'm using Behat to do some automated Testing and I've added Mink with its Goutte driver.
I'm using the latest version of Behat and Mink.

I've added the Mink Extension to the Feature Context file and it works when I run a simple feature like:

```
Feature:...
  Scenario: See A Blog Post
    Given I am on the homepage
    And I follow "login"
    Then I should be on "/login"
    And I should see "Login"
```

However when I try the next step and try and fill in some fields:

```
    And I fill in "username" with "admin"
```

Where username:

`<input class="input-field" type="text" id="username"/>`

I get the following error:

```
Malformed field path "" (InvalidArgumentException)
```

Any help will be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Have you fixed this? What was the solution? Just came across with this while having the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you do not have a `name="username"` attribute on your field. I am having a similar problem but I am trying to test a Stripe instance which you cannot have name attributes. It appears `id` and `title` are not working.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The ticked answer fixed this for me.

I also found you can fill in forms using the following syntax:

```
When I fill in the following:
  | username            | admin              |
  | email               | myemail@domain.com |
  | password            | 5uP3r5ecUr3P4s5w0rD|
```

I also created a custom FeatureContext function to help find other elements:

```
protected function findElementBySelector($selector)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $element = $page->find('css', $selector);

    if (null === $element) {
        throw new \Exception(
            sprintf('Element with %s not found.', $selector));
    }

    return $element;
}
```

This function was used by others to find the element and perform an action to it:

```
/**
 * @Then I click the element :selector
 */
public function iClickTheElement($selector)
{
    $link = $this->findElementBySelector($selector);
    $link->click();
}
```

I used this in my .feature like this:

```
And I ...
And I click the element ".my-link"
Then I ...
```

Where .my-link = `<a href="http://domain.com" class="my-link">My Link</a>`

The link below helped create my custom FeatureContext function:
http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/traversing-pages.html